# Change color of elements before element

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make rating. I have no idea how to make previous elements get style of checked element.

**CSS**

```
.give-rate label i {
  color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.give-rate .selected i {
   color: gold;
}
```

**HTML**

```
{% for radio in rating.Rate %}
 {{form_widget(radio)}}
 <label for="{{radio.vars.id}}" id="star-{{radio.vars.value}}" class="required">
   <i class="fas fa-star" id="{{radio.vars.value}}" onclick="pick({{radio.vars.value}})"></i>
 </label>
{% endfor %}
```

**JS**

```
function pick(id) {
 const star = document.getElementById("star-" + id);
 const stars = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
 while (stars.length > 0) {
  stars[0].classList.remove("selected");
 }

 star.classList.add("selected");
}
```

This is working (picking one selected star from five and changes it color to gold) but I want stars that are behind selected one change color also.

I've tried changing css to:

```
.give-rate .selected::before i,
.give-rate .selected i {
  color: gold;
}
```

but this way none star was changing color.

Is there anyone who can tell what should I do?

Comment: It would help, if you can add a minimal working code for this.

Comment: add the code in js fiddle so that it helps to understand code better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a selector that would apply on an element, and all of the previous siblings.

You should use JavaScript to apply the `selected` class to the hovered star, and also the previous ones.